# How do I filter/sort on Hair color with radiobutton from array list using a Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

**I have a page with characters, I want to display the characters with a black hair color when user clicks on the radiobutton**

```
<div id="filters">Filters settings</br>
    <p>Hair color</p>
    <input type="radio" id="AllHair" name="HairColor" value="AllHair">
    <label for="AllHair">Show all hair</label>
    <input type="radio" id="BlondeHair" name="HairColor" value="BlondeHair">
    <label for="BlondeHair">Show blonde hair</label>
    <input type="radio" id="BlackHair" name="HairColor" value="BlackHair">
    <label for="BlackHair">Show black hair</label>
</div>
```

**This is my Javascript I have so far, idk how to finish it**

```
    function SortByHairColor(){
    let retourString = `<tr class="row" style="background-color: ${colors[house]}">
    <td id="column" class="column">${name}</td>
    <td id="column" class="column">${actor}</td>
    <td id="column" class="column"><img src="${image}"/></td>
</tr>`;

  for (let  i= 0; i < rdbHairColor.length; i++){
    if (rdbHairColor[i].checked){
      retourString += rdbHairColor[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  divToonGeslacht.innerHTML = retourString;
}
```

**My init function**

```
function Init()
{
    debugger;
    //start page
    const text = potterCharacters.map(character => {
        const { name, actor, image, house} = character
        return `<tr class="row" style="background-color: ${colors[house]}">
            <td id="column" class="column">${name}</td>
            <td id="column" class="column">${actor}</td>
            <td id="column" class="column"><img src="${image}"/></td>
        </tr>`
    })
    document.getElementById("rows").innerHTML = text ;
    filters = document.getElementById("filters");
    rdbHairColor = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="HairColor"][type="radio"]');

    rdbHairColor.addEventListener('change',SortByHairColor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated my answer. Here you can see how I use `array.filter()` to find the characters with the selected haircolor.

HTML

```
<p>Please select haircolor</p>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="hair1" name="haircolor" value="black">
  <label for="hair1">black</label>
  <input type="radio" id="hair2" name="haircolor" value="red">
  <label for="hair2">red</label>
  <input type="radio" id="hair1" name="haircolor" value="brown">
  <label for="hair3">brown</label>
</div>
<table id="result"></table>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
const resultField = document.querySelector("#result")
const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="haircolor"][type="radio"]')

let potterCharacters = [{name:"ron", haircolor:"red"}, {name:"hermione", haircolor:"brown"}, {name:"harry", haircolor:"black"}, {name:"snape", haircolor:"black"}]

for(let btn of radioButtons) {
    btn.addEventListener("change", (e) => updateSelection(e))
}

function updateSelection(e) {
  resultField.innerHTML = `<tr><td>NAME</td><td>HAIRCOLOR</td></tr>`
  let selection = potterCharacters.filter(char => char.haircolor == e.target.value)
  for(let character of selection) {
     let tr = document.createElement("tr")
     tr.innerHTML = `<td>${character.name}</td><td>${character.haircolor}</td>`
     resultField.appendChild(tr)
  }
}
```

Check the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xs40ahv/1/) here :)

Comment: rdbHairColor is in my Init function and potterCharacters is the array Of characters(to big to post here) but But how do I impleent this in the function

Comment: ```let potterCharacters = [
    {
      name: "Harry Potter",
      species: "human",
      gender: "male",
      house: "Gryffindor",
      dateOfBirth: "31-07-1980",
      yearOfBirth: 1980,
      ancestry: "half-blood",
      eyeColour: "green",
      hairColour: "black",
      patronus: "stag",
      hogwartsStudent: true,
      hogwartsStaff: false,
      actor: "Daniel Radcliffe",
      alive: true,
      image: "http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/harry.jpg"
    },```

Comment: I updated the answer, you can see it working on JSFiddle :)